# Microservices doesnt register in Eureka with AWS fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, aws-fargate

I am trying to deploy my spring boot microservices in AWS ECS. I was able to run Eureka container as a task and it is working fine. But when I run any other micoservice with AWS Fargate, it's log shows

`[ main] c.n.e.transport.JerseyReplicationClient : Cannot find localhost ip
java.net.UnknownHostException: 4terdtrtxxx: 53543xxxxd: Name does not resolve
at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
...`
. I think the problem is when I run with AWS Fargate, springboot unable to identify it's ip address to register in Eureka. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that eureka client does not get the correct IP from Fargate metadata service.
I solved this by overwriting the IP (called that metadata service myself).
I created [a sample](https://github.com/jussiseppala/eurekafargatesample) which shows how to do that.

I hope that similar feature would be included at some point to eureka client.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method if you are using spring cloud:

```
@Bean
public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils){
    EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
    String ip = null;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    config.setIpAddress(ip);
    config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
    return config;
}
```